# Wordpress - How to show only two sentences in preview the_excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

I need my preview show only two sentences, how can I do it?

```
    add_filter(
    'the_excerpt',
    function ($excerpt) {
      return substr($excerpt,0,strpos($excerpt,'.')+1);
    }
  );

  function excerpt_read_more_link($output) {
      global $post;
      $output = preg_replace('/(.*?[?!.](?=\s|$)).*/', '\\0', $output);
      if(mb_strlen($output) > 300) {
          $output = mb_substr($output, 0, 300);
        }
        return $output; 
    }
    add_filter('the_excerpt', 'excerpt_read_more_link');
```

I have a code, that make it for first one sentence, but how can I fix it to show two?

Comment: @splash58 I need the forst two sentences, not just the second and third

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/RcrNkq/2 - get now

Comment: @splash58 doesn't work for me either